# Is it safe to splice an output extension onto an AC Power Adapter?

Tags: ac, identification, adapter

(first post, trying my best to follow the rules :D)

I recently bought a Cintiq 27qHD tablet, and an Ergotron arm (with an extra arm segment) to mount it.
The intended way to do this is to run the output cable from the adapter inside the hollow ergo arm.
Unfortunately, the output cable is not long enough to comfortably run the full length and make the turns it needs to.

The connector type is apparently a type of DC connector known as a "power-DIN" or a Kycon KPPX-4P. It's similar to a DIN and Mini-DIN but not quite.

the adapter is rated 24v and 5A, if that helps. The manuafacturer is "Adapter Tech".

If anyone has a better idea other than splicing in an extension between the adapter and the connector, I'm very open to suggestions!

Cheers,

-Garrett

Comment: That connector looks something like a "Mini-DIN" plug - similar to a S-Video plug but with larger pins.  I've seen these available as parts but can't recall where.

Comment: Agh, I thought you were correct but now I'm really unsure. It looks quite a bit thicker than the pictures of Mini-DIN's I'm seeing online. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously if it looks like a bigger version of the Mini-DIN, [it must be a DIN connector.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector)

> The original DIN standards for these connectors are no longer in print and have been replaced with the equivalent international standard IEC 60130-9.
>
> While DIN connectors appear superficially similar to the newer professional XLR connectors, they are not compatible

Alternatively, it could be a *"power DIN"* connector, which isn't a DIN standard at all. [Also known as a 4 pin power connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_connector#Kycon) ([Mouser Link](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kycon/KPPX-4P/?qs=%2Fha2pyFadugoYYrkg1Kn5n6NwEKIIyLaR8%2FL1%252bHtlYw%3D))

> A male 4-pin "Kycon" power connector, which appears similar to a Mini-DIN connector

[image]

As for cutting and splicing the connector, yes, that's possible, and can be done safely. Just make sure your extension is of a similar gauge wire for the voltage and current that it will carry. Standard cable splicing technique should be followed, nothing special about it.

Comment: That looks like the one! It seems traditional DIN was mostly used for data, with only this mention of them being used for power:

"Oddly, later versions of the Atari 8-bit computers as well as Commodore C64 and Elektronika BK used a DIN connector for their AC adapter"

I'll continue to look for an extension cable, but if I can't find one, I'm still curious about splicing. thank you!

Comment: @Garrettorious see my edits.